# How can I call setup in Moq twice in one method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have a unit test method that needs to mock (stub?) two repository method calls in the class that I'm testing.  Every example I've worked through until now shows one setup method for the Mock, but now I need two.

Example:

```
_employeeRepositoryMock.Setup(e => e.GetEmployees())
            .Returns(new Employee[]
                     {
                        new Employee
                        {
                            Name = "John Doe"
                        }
                     });
_employeeRepositoryMock.Setup(e => e.UpdateEmployee(1)).Returns(true);

Assert.IsTrue(_employeeService.UpdateEmployeeRecords() > 0);
_employeeRepositoryMock.Verify(gr => gr.UpdateEmployee(1), Times.Exactly(1));
```

In this example I need to mock two repository methods that are both called in "UpdateEmployeeRecords()" but I'm not sure how.

**Update**

Scratch this entire question -- I overlooked something simple.  I was passing in the wrong numerical value for UpdateEmployee which was causing the Assert to fail.  I changed the parameter in the mock to It.IsAny instead to get it to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way by creating the type of data the method should return (in my case a `List<int>` and a `List<string>`) and return it using the `.Returns`. Now whenever the `DoSomething()` method is called it will return my intResult List as the mocked data and the stringResult List when the `DoSomethingElseThatIsReallyCool()` method is called:

```
//Test method
{
  List<int> intResult = new List<int>();
  intResult.Add(0);

  List<string> stringResult = new List<string>();
  stringResult.Add("test");

  _reposMock.Setup(r=>r.DoSomething()).Returns(intResult);
  _reposMock.Setup(r=>r.DoSomethingElseThatIsReallyCool()).Returns(stringResult);

  Assert.IsTrue(_reposMock.SomeMethod() > 0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry amurra, by making my example so generic your answer was lost in the translation.  Please see my edit above.  My Assert fails and I suspect it's due to the second setup call.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup methods appear to be fine.  Your Assertion must be failing for some other reason.  Some thoughts:

1. Have you tried debugging your test to see what's going on?
2. Is 1 the correct value to be mocking in your UpdateEmployee method?
3. (Pardon me if this is patronizing, but I've done this before) Are you passing your mock to your service via _employeeRepositoryMock.Object?